# How to generate or add balance in my btc testnet address

Tags: testnet

I am trying to add btc testnet, I have read that these following sites offers testnet btc but upon checking their servers were down

https://bcoin.io/
https://bitpay.com/insight/#/ALL/mainnet/home
https://api.bitcore.io/api/BTC/testnet/

Is there any other platform or way I can add balance in my testnet address so I can try transferring and viewing transactions in test mode?

Answer (score 1):

https://xmr.to **has discontinued their service so this will not work anymore:** https://xmr.to/blog/job-done

This workaround involves exchanging XMR(stagenet) to BTC(testnet). Everything is free and you get XMR(stagenet) from step 2 mentioned below. Questions and answers involving altcoins are offtopic on https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com however other bitcoin testnet faucets aren't working, so it's just a workaround to solve the problem and get free testnet bitcoin in few minutes

I always use this faucet and it works for me. Tried before posting this answer and got 0.05 tBTC in this transaction: https://blockstream.info/testnet/tx/86b2ae07645d664085a52e7474dac531e9b8c5790028162a7be9383a955fea33

1. Go to https://test.xmr.to/ and enter bitcoin address to receive testnet coins with amount less than 0.1
2. Proceed to next step, copy XMR address from payment instructions, open https://community.xmr.to/faucet/stagenet/ in another tab and paste the XMR address you copied earlier.
3. Click "submit" and if you don't see any error, tBTC will be sent to your address in few minutes

You can also share your testnet address with the question. If this faucet doesn't work I can send you small amount for testing or maybe someone else.

[image: faucet-image]

Comment: There is no reason to use XMR (Monero) to get testnet Bitcoin

Comment: @MichaelFolkson _end goal_ is to get testnet bitcoin for free so I am not sure how does it matter if it involves a testnet website that allows you to exchange XMR (stagenet) to BTC (testnet) for free with few steps.

Comment: I guess it doesn't matter if there are no alternatives. Please make it clear though at the top of the answer that this method requests testnet (stagenet) Monero and then swaps it for testnet Bitcoin. Also that there is a dearth of Bitcoin testnet faucets and this is one of the only working faucets at the current time. It looks spammy to direct an individual asking a question on the Bitcoin StackExchange to an altcoin site otherwise.

Comment: Done. Mentioned everything in bold.

Comment: Cool, reversed my initial downvote and upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to rent some hash power, or have an ASIC to mine testnet coins (unfortunately).

Regtest, on the other hand lets you run a local blockchain on your machine so you can generate new coins immediately. These can only be used on regtest, but should let you do most of the testing you need.  You can access regtest by adding `regtest=1` in your bitcoin.conf file. Then you can generate coins using the console or cli with the `generatetoaddress` command.