# Selling Test bitcoin

Tags: testnet, sell-bitcoins

I have a random and maybe crazy question. Can I sell test coins? Someone recently told me that Advanced Market Terminal is buying them. It is strange to me Since they should hold no value.

Comment: I don't think anyone needs to pay anything for testnet coins: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/99511/

Comment: I don't think this should be voted as off-topic: OP hasn't asked about *where* to sell coins, they've asked about the *possibility/viability* of selling them. That question has an answer, which is not expected to change, as the functionality of testnet is dependant on tBTC having no monetary value.

Answer (score 1):

Testnet coins are an interesting thing:

- They are useful because they have no value
- If they had value, they would be useless

Remember that the testnet is there to test out your code, and ensure that everything runs smoothly *before* you deploy that code to an environment which is holding actual value. That way, if something goes wrong, you haven't lost anything of value.

So you certainly *could* sell someone testnet coins, but I'm not sure why anyone would pay you for them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want larger amounts of testnet coins (0.1 or more), you still need to run a miner to get testnet coins and the amount of testnet coins is still limited to 21 million like maininet. So I can see why someone might want to pay a small amount for testnet coins just so they don't have to wait for the mining process.

If no blocks are found on testnet in 20 minutes it will reset difficulty back to 1, which is the lowest difficulty making finding a block very easy.

So I suppose it depends on the patience of the person, if no patience then maybe you can find a buyer, but the difficulty reset is supposed to help keep the value at or near zero.

Comment: A developer wanting to test their code doesn't need to mine tbtc to get it, there has always been many active testnet faucets that give it away free and fast.

Comment: I should clarify I was referring to getting larger amounts to test with. There are very few faucets and they only give out small amounts.  If someone wants 0.1 tBTC or more a faucet is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Testnet coins do not have an official value. Most people will not pay anything for Testnet coins, and there are no markets that I know of that would exchange tBTC. However, if you have a large amount someone might pay for large volume. Testnet is supposed to be free though.

Comment: I guess the advanced market is also a trade security broker.. but they also focus on digital currency app development and this is why they buy Test coine as well. .... ‍♀️‍♀️‍♀️ I did not think a place like this exist. But my source also could be wrong, who knows