# History of Bitcoin's Networks

Tags: testnet, regtest, history

Bitcoin main net was launched on January 3, 2009 at 19:15:05 UTC. But what is the history of the two other network options in Bitcoin: `testnet` and `regtest`?

I think `testnet` is on version 3, what was version 2, 1 (and 0)? And when was the `regtest` option added to Bitcoin Core?

Comment: Related to https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9975/has-the-testnet-ever-been-reset but also asks about `regtest` network option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regtest was added in version 0.9.0 which was released in March 2014

> Add '-regtest' mode, similar to testnet but private with instant block generation with 'setgenerate' RPC.

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/release-notes/release-notes-0.9.0.md

Testnet's history: [Has the TestNet ever been reset?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9975/has-the-testnet-ever-been-reset)

There is one more chain which is used for testing: Signet

It was added in https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/18267 (2020)

Comment: I heard that testnet version 3 was introduced because people starting putting a price on the version2 testnet coins. But the linked answer does not tell that story. Can anyone confirm or deny?

Comment: Not sure about story but I have seen few people looking to sell testnet coins which is wrong: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/99604/selling-test-bitcoin

Comment: Wrong? That's just like your opinion, man.